# $f(f(x)) = 4x+3$; $\forall x \in \mathbb{N}$ and $f(5^k) = 5^k \times 2^{k-2} + 2^{k-3}$. Find $f(2015)$.

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

> For all positive integer $x$,  $f(f(x)) = 4x+3$;  and for **ONLY ONE** positive integer $k$, $f(5^k) = 5^k \times 2^{k-2} + 2^{k-3}$. Find $f(2015)$.

Dont know where to start. Any hint will be helpful. **Dont give full solution**.
**Source**: BdMO 2016 Dhaka regional Higher Secondary.

Comment: what is $f$? what is its domain and codomain?

Comment: This is the exact problem statement.  The main function is for all positive number

Comment: have you been able to find a function that works (trial and error works easily)? at least that way you'll be able to find the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort of a hint:  Since $f(f(x))$ is linear, I suspect that so is $f(x)$.  I assumed that $f(x) = ax+b$ and was able to get the answer.

Comment: $f(x) = 2x+1$? I get this.

Comment: yes, that one works, of course the "tought" part of the problem is proving that any function that works must have $f(2015)=4031$.  Although this will probably earn you $2$ points out of $7$.

Comment: And there are some other proofs that I need to show. like there is only one integer $k$ for which the second equation works. And there might be some small thing. After that I will have at-least 5/7 ?

Answer (score 2):

Hint 1: f(x) is injective

Hint 2:$2017=503\cdot 4+3,503=4\cdot 125+3$